# Specify more than one item in the where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, delete-row

Is there any way I could run the following 'logical code' to actually work?

```
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id='3,4,5,9'");
```

I basically want to give my user a tick box to tick for all displayed rows, they can then pick which ones to remove. I just want to remove more than one row with the id's specified?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about :

```
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (3, 4, 5, 9)");
```

Provided :

- your ids are numeric in the DB
- you want to delete user 3, and delete user 4, and delete user 5, and delete user 9

And, of course, if your ids are strings :

```
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN ('3', '4', '5', '9')");
```

For more informations, see :

- [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)
- And, why not : [Subqueries with ANY, IN, and SOME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

Comment: The arguments to `IN()` don't have to be numeric.  They just have to be values.

Comment: @Bill : what I meant is "don't use quotes if numeric, as those would not be needed -- I've eddited my post to add the same example considering ids are strings, hoping it'll make my words more clear)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification.  I had given you +1 already anyway. :-)

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator for that.

```
DELETE ... WHERE id IN (3,4,5,9)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `WHERE IN` clause.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (3, 4, 5, 9);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in` instead of `=`.

E.g.,

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (3,4,5,9);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `IN`

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE id IN (3,4,5,9)
```

Although in my applications I never delete anything. Instead I have an active flag that I set to false.

```
UPDATE users set active=0 where id in (3,4,5,9)
```

All queries then have a where clause for `active=1` and 1 is the default value for the active flag in the table.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE * FROM table WHERE id IN (3,4,5,9)");
```